# summarize overlap with python

Tags: python, pandas, overlap

I am analyzing DNA/Protein sequence data with python and got a problem.
Here is the table of DNA sequence.

[image]

I want to analyze them as group1 and group2 are pair.
For example, AAATTT_TTTCCC or GGGCCC_GGAAA are pairs.

This sequence data sometimes shows same sequence.
For instance, AAATTT appeared three times and AGTC did twice.
I want to count this overlap sequence and summarize as below.
I wonder I should use pandas, but don't know how to do this.
If anyone could help this, I would be grateful with that very much.

[image]

Comment: So you just want to count the number of times each unique Group1 value appears? Why is Group2 a column in your summary table?

Comment: Oh, I also want the group2 sequence if Group1 sequence is same!

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of appearances of each unique value in a column:

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# load data into Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

# get counts for each unique Group1 value
df["Group1"].value_counts()
```

Comment: Do you also know how to show Group2 as I mentioned above?

Comment: This one-liner should do it: `df.sort_values("Group1")[["Group1", "Group2"]].join(df["Group1"].value_counts().to_frame("Group1 Count"), on="Group1")`

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!!